# Print to 2 printer by default

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, pdf, printing, sp3

Is it possible to print directly to two printers simultaneously? What I want to do is every time user prints a receipt it should print to PDF and to default printer. Is there any printer driver that does that?

OS info : MS Windows XP Pro SP3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the moderator at social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverprint/thread/c83c326a-4b92-4297-88bd-0595eaaffdad) : "As far as I know, we cannot use a build-in tool or settings to send print job to multiple printers simultaneously. It is possible however to use a third party application or customized program".

[This Google Answers thread](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/610328.html) mentions solutions :

- Solution 1: LEADTOOLS ePrint:
  http://www.eprintdriver.com/ePrintFilePrinter.html
  Here is the specific feature in this application that you need:
  http://www.eprintdriver.com/eprint-broadcastprinting.html
  Download a 30 day trial here: http://www.eprintdriver.com/free-evaluation.htm
- Solution 2: INTELLIscribe:
  http://lpr.brooksnet.com/index.html
  The specific feature is discussed here:
  http://lpr.brooksnet.com/broadcast-printing.html (This one might need
  ip addresses printers) but you can try out the trial here:
  http://www.brooksnet.com/cgi-bin/cs/download.html?dl_product=IS32
- Solution 3: Print Distributor
  http://www.printdistributor.com/
  "Flexible actions allow you to send copies of prints to as many
  locations as you require."
  Free Trial: http://www.frogmorecs.com/Download/SetupPD.exe
- Solution 4: PrintRush:
  http://www.zfirm.com/products/printrush.shtml
  "Can print to multiple printers across the LAN or WAN."